# How do I POST to my org's REST API from outside the org?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I can't find a sample script using curl or some equivalent to allow me to post to my org. When I write one myself, I keep getting authentication or 400 errors and I'm suspecting that it's the way I'm setting up the script/command and not including all the information that's needed to make a call.

My class is basically following this example (using RestResource), but I can't figure out how to POST data to it: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST

Thanks

Comment: I would be good to see what kind of curl you are trying to execute. Here you can see examples about how to use standard api - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart.htm

Comment: Are you providing authentication information? Here is [one way](http://www.oyecode.com/2014/07/try-any-salesforce-api-quickly-with.html).

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test case based on the POST examples from the [article you linked to](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST#Using_POST.2C_PUT_and_PATCH).

Example Apex class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/resttestapi/*')
global with sharing class RestTestController {

    @HttpPost 
    global static String createNewCase(String companyName, String caseType) {
         System.debug('COMPANY: '+companyName);
         System.debug('CASE TYPE: '+caseType);
         return 'Done COMPANY: ' + companyName + ' CASE TYPE:' + caseType ;
    }

}
```

Here is how I call it using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) in Chrome.

[image]

Note that my dev org has a namespace (DFB) defined, so that gets added into the URL. E.g.

```
https://na5.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/DFB/resttestapi/
```

If you didn't have a namespace it would be:

```
https://na5.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/resttestapi/
```

In terms of translating that into a cURL commend... I've had a go, but it might be slightly off as I don't have easy access to it.

```
curl https://na5.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/DFB/resttestapi/ 
    -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D700000000001!AQoAQKmECXaoin5_Yvk_NOTmyREALsessionID_fgSacOE.x8rlCt3nfEFSSROD2LSM4dBr0000"
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -d "@sample.json"
```

**sample.json** file contains:

```
{"companyName":"GenePoint","caseType":"Software"}
```

---

The value after the Authorization Bearer is a valid Session ID. (A.K.A access_token). [Examples of getting the required value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm).